# jQuery Flot.js: Get only currently visible data points

Tags: jquery, flot

I need to get the currently visible data points after zooming (or panning, if you bind that event as well).

Flot provides a few methods but none that I can figure out for the currently visible data points.

```
$("#graphContainer").bind("plotzoom", function (event, plot) {
    getCurrentData(plot);
});

function getCurrentData(plot) {
    console.log(plot.getAxes());
    console.log(plot.getData());
};
```

The `getAxes()` method gives you access to the ranges, and current ticks. The `getData()` method gives you access to ALL data points, in an array (`var points = plot.getData(); => points[0].data`).

I haven't found a way to extract only the visible points after zooming, which is what I'm trying to do. I'd greatly appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do that yourself using the [array filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function with something like

```
var plotData = plot.getData()[0];
var visiblePoints = plotData.data.filter(dp =>
    dp[0] >= plotData.xaxis.min && dp[0] <= plotData.xaxis.max &&
    dp[1] >= plotData.yaxis.min && dp[1] <= plotData.yaxis.max);
```

Comment: This is exactly and precisely what I needed. I would've never figured this out on my own. Thank you very much.